# Ordering of month/year pairs in T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I am writing a stored procedure for displaying month and year. It is working, but it is not returning the rows in the desired order.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[audioblog_getarchivedates]  
as  
begin  
select DateName(Month,a.createddate) + ' ' + DateName(Year,a.createddate) as ArchiveDate 
from audio_blog a 
group by DateName(Month,a.createddate) + ' ' + DateName(Year,a.createddate) 
order by DateName(Month,a.createddate) + ' ' + DateName(Year,a.createddate) desc
end
```

Results will come like this:

> March 2010
>   January 2010
>   February 2010

But that is not in a order (desc).

Comment: M > J > F... It is indeed in descending order. You're searching alphabetically, not by date... and the J in January comes after the F in February in the alphabet. See thekaido's answer... for resolution

Comment: trigger happy much? lol. the accepted answer is definitely not the solution to the question as stated. It may have helped you get to the solution but what good does this do the next person who looks at this question? How did a one line statement that is invalid in the sproc given solve your problem? At least update your question with the final code. SO is about give and take, not just take. Cheer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution but should work until you figure it out.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Audioblog_getarchivedates] 
AS 
  BEGIN 
    SELECT DISTINCT Datename(MONTH,a.DATE) + ' ' + Datename(YEAR,a.DATE) AS archivedate,
    Cast(Datename(MONTH,a.DATE) + ' ' + Datename(YEAR,a.DATE) AS DATETIME) AS tmp
    FROM audio_blog a 
    ORDER BY tmp DESC 
  END
```

Comment: ya i change my answer ya it is perfect now it is working fine thank you Mr.Sky Sanders

Answer (score 4):

Jeff Smith has written an [excellent article](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/09/10/group-by-month-sql.aspx) on methods how to group and order by Year-Month pairs. I like especially his approach of rounding the date to the first day of the month and grouping by that value:

```
GROUP BY dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, SomeDate),0)
```

It's faster because it doesn't require string concatenation.

You can convert this value to a year-month combination later on in the query by executing `YEAR` and `MONTH` on it for a user-friendly representation.

Answer (score 2):

You want to order by a datetime value, but your groups don't have that. One way is to pick one of the createddates arbitrarily (e.g. the MAX) within each group, and ordewr by those:

```
select ArchiveDate from (
select DateName(Month,a.createddate) + ' ' + DateName(Year,a.createddate) as ArchiveDate, MAX(createddate) as createddate
from (select CONVERT(datetime,createddate) as createddate from (select '20100101' as createddate union all select '20100201' union all select '20100301') t) a 
group by DateName(Month,a.createddate) + ' ' + DateName(Year,a.createddate) ) g
order by g.createddate desc
```

Comment: +1, bur the outer select is not necessary. You could use MAX(createddate) directly in ORDER BY, without putting it into SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this type of problem with a subquery. The inner query has both the DisplyName and SortIndex.
The outer query displays the name but sorts on the index.

e.g

```
select a,b,c DisplayName   from
(select a, b,c, DisplayName, SortIndex....

) as Temp
order by Temp.SortIndex
```

You can use this general approach with any number of fields simply by adding a display/index pair

Answer (score 0):

End it with:

```
order by a.createddate desc
```

Comment: Agree, the date will order properly regardless of format. When you format like you were you are ordering a string, not a date.

Comment: Mr.thekaido it is giving error like this

Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Procedure audioblog_getarchivedates, Line 5
Column "audio_blog.createddate" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: ya i got it thank you for response Mr. thekaido it is help full to me

Comment: @Surya ? trying to imagine how this can be correct. please help me.

Answer (score -2):

order by 1 (desc)